# Obtaining and returning a permit from a semaphore in a shell script

Tags: bash, ipc, semaphore

In a shell script I can use:

```
ipcmk -S 4
```

To create a semaphore with 4 slots. With `ipcrm` I could delete the semaphore again. But how can I use it? I cannot find any semwait, ipcsemget or similar. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

I made this tool just today as I was facing the same problem: https://github.com/aybabtme/semaphore